Convert this numpy code to torch to genearte Levy process
I have this function to generate Levy stocashtic procee using Merton Jump
np.random.seed(4)
#generate the merton jump

def merton_jump_paths_numpy( T, r, sigma,  lam, m, v, steps, Npaths):
    size=(steps,Npaths)
    dt = T/steps
    poi_rv = np.multiply(np.random.poisson( lam*dt, size=size),
                     np.random.normal(m,v, size=size)).cumsum(axis=0)
    geo = np.cumsum(((r -  sigma**2/2 -lam*(m  + v**2*0.5))*dt +\
                          sigma*np.sqrt(dt) * \
                          np.random.normal(size=size)), axis=0)

    return np.exp(geo+poi_rv)

I initial the paramaters and call the function as follows:
S = 100 # current stock price
T = 1 # time to maturity
r = 0.02 # risk free rate
m = 0 # meean of jump size
v = 0.3 # standard deviation of jump
lam =1 # intensity of jump i.e. number of jumps per annum
steps =10000 # time steps
Npaths = 1 # number of paths to simulate
sigma = 0.2 # annaul standard deviation , for weiner process

j = merton_jump_paths_numpy(T, r, sigma, lam, m, v, steps, Npaths)

plt.plot(j)
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.title('Jump Diffusion Process')
plt.show()

It works fine.
But,  I need to convert this numpy-based code to torch tensors. Mainly i should to have the variables poi_rv, geo  and the np.exp(geo+poi_rv) as tensors instead of numpy.
I tried to break down the code and calculate the poi_rv, geo  and the np.exp(geo+poi_rv) as follows:
 
np.random.seed(4)
torch.manual_seed(4)
def merton_jump_paths( T, r, sigma,  lam, m, v, steps, Npaths):
    size=(steps,Npaths)
    dt = T/steps
    ran= torch.rand(steps,Npaths) * 1  
    tttt = torch.poisson(ran)
    normal_rv_torch = torch.normal(m, v, size=size)
    normal_rv_cumsum_torch = torch.cumsum(normal_rv_torch, dim=0)

    poi_rv_torch = torch.mul(tttt,normal_rv_cumsum_torch)
    
    drift_term = torch.tensor(r) - torch.tensor(sigma) **2 / 2.0 - 
    torch.tensor(lam) * (torch.tensor(m) + torch.tensor(v)**2 / 2.0) 
    * torch.tensor(dt)
    diffusion_term = torch.tensor(sigma) * 
       torch.sqrt(torch.tensor(dt)) *  np.random.normal(size=size)
    geo_tprch = torch.cumsum(drift_term + diffusion_term, dim=0)
    return np.exp(geo+poi_rv), torch.exp(geo_tprch + poi_rv_torch)


But this did not work. I got so far plot.
